# How to divide the dataset into all the possible combination of test and train in R?

Tags: r

```
    I have a dataset with 90 rows and 5 columns ,of which 4 independent variables and one is dependent variable .I need to split the dataset into test and train Leaving one out cross validation .For example 90th train ,rest all test ....89th train ..rest all train and so on


  Below is the code which I tried ,its not working
```

K=90
    folds <- rep_len(1:nrFolds, nrow(data))

```
# actual cross validation
for(k in 1:nrFolds) {
  # actual split of the data
  print(k)
  fold <- which(folds == k)
  data.train <- data[-fold,]
  dim(data.train)
  data.test <- data[fold,]
  dim(data.test)

}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated .After this I need to send this test and train datset to the classifier for training and testing.
    Thanks

Comment: `2^90 = 1.24x10^27` is a rather large number of combinations. Surely you don't want to split your data into *all* possible train/test combinations.

Comment: there will be 90 combination as I discussed in the question ...89 train ,1 test ..88 train , 2 test .....87 train ,3 test and so on

Comment: There is a difference between 90 random combinations (stratified according to size) and all possible combinations. Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: yes right .I need only 90 combination of test and train

Comment: Is the methodology sound? Towards the end you will end up with 1 Train & 89 Test

Comment: I want to see whats the accuracy of the model for this 90 combination of test and train..thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code splits 70% of the data selected randomly into training set and the remaining 30% sample into test data set.

```
data<-read.csv("c:/datafile.csv")

dt = sort(sample(nrow(data), nrow(data)*.7))
train<-data[dt,]
test<-data[-dt,]
```

Here is another good, very good and very generic, example.

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Smarket)
smp_siz = floor(0.75*nrow(Smarket))  # creates a value for dividing the data into train and test. In this case the value is defined as 75% of the number of rows in the dataset
smp_siz  # shows the value of the sample size

set.seed(123)   # set seed to ensure you always have same random numbers generated
train_ind = sample(seq_len(nrow(Smarket)),size = smp_siz)  # Randomly identifies therows equal to sample size ( defined in previous instruction) from  all the rows of Smarket dataset and stores the row number in train_ind
train =Smarket[train_ind,] #creates the training dataset with row numbers stored in train_ind
test=Smarket[-train_ind,]  # creates the test dataset excluding the row numbers mentioned in train_ind

require(caTools)  # loading caTools library

## Loading required package: caTools

set.seed(123)   #  set seed to ensure you always have same random numbers generated
sample = sample.split(Smarket,SplitRatio = 0.75) # splits the data in the ratio mentioned in SplitRatio. After splitting marks these rows as logical TRUE and the the remaining are marked as logical FALSE
train1 =subset(Smarket,sample ==TRUE) # creates a training dataset named train1 with rows which are marked as TRUE
test1=subset(Smarket, sample==FALSE)
```

https://rpubs.com/ID_Tech/S1

Also, see this.

https://edumine.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/splitting-a-data-frame-into-training-and-testing-sets-in-r/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly: (I have used the mtcars dataset, as you did not provide data with your question)

```
res <- lapply(1: (nrow(mtcars)-1), function(n){
  train_idx <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars), n)
  list(train = mtcars[train_idx,], test = mtcars[-train_idx,])
})
```

This generates the following list:

```
str(res, max.level = 2)
List of 31
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ train:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ test :'data.frame':   31 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ train:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ test :'data.frame':   30 obs. of  11 variables:
...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ train:'data.frame':   30 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ test :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ train:'data.frame':   31 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ test :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  11 variables:
```

For which each item contains the requested train and test df. As pointed out by others, this will generate a different combination of observations each time you run it. (maybe `set.seed(1)` beforehand?). I also have not seen this type of split before.

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted .Thanks ..But how to apply classifier model to this output....      I need to apply this naive bayes classifier for all the combination         NBclassfier=naiveBayes(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=traindata)

Comment: If you only want to use the train data of each split for the naiveBayers, you can something like `lapply(res, function(split){NBclassfier = naiveBayes(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, data = split$train)})`

Comment: or shorter in formula notation `map(res, ~NBclassfier = naiveBayes(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, data = .x$train)})`